# Exception not caught in try catch block

Tags: c++, exception

I do a simple *throw "TEST THROW"* and it isn't caught in my *catch (std::exception& e)*. Is it because I'm catching an *std::exception& e*? I mean, are only exception classes derived from std::exception caught? If not, am I doing something wrong or is it normal? By the way, none of the two catch blocks caught the throw exception.

```
int main()
{
try
{
    throw "TEST THROW"; // TEST
    Core core;

    core.Init();
    core.Load();

    while (!core.requestCloseWindow)
    {
        core.HandleInput();

        core.Update();
        core.Draw();
    }

    core.Unload();
    core.window->close();
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    try
    {
        time_t rawTime;
        struct tm* timeInfo;
        char timeBuffer [80];

        time(&rawTime);
        timeInfo = localtime(&rawTime);

        strftime(timeBuffer, 80, "%F %T", timeInfo);
        puts(timeBuffer);

        std::ofstream ofs; // Pas besoin de close, car le destructeur le fait.
        ofs.exceptions(std::ofstream::failbit | std::ofstream::badbit);
        ofs.open("log.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
        ofs << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "An error occured while writing to a log file!" << std::endl;
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: You are not throwing an object of type `std::exception`, so the exception is not caught by the catch clause designed to catch objects of type `std::exception`.

Comment: I think you can use catch (const char*) or string.

Comment: What did you expect to happen? What would `e` be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're throwing a `const char*`. `std::exception` only catches `std::exception` and all derived classes of it. So in order to catch your throw, you should throw `std::runtime_error("TEST THROW")` instead. Or `std::logic_error("TEST THROW")`; whatever fits better. The derived classes of `std::exception` are [listed here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception).

Answer (score 15):

Another reason people may hit this issue, especially if they've been writing Java recently, is that they may be throwing *a pointer to the exception*.

```
/* WARNING WARNING THIS CODE IS WRONG DO NOT COPY */
try {
    throw new std::runtime_error("catch me");
} catch (std::runtime_error &err) {
    std::cerr << "exception caught and ignored: " << err.what() << std::end;
}
/* WARNING WARNING THIS CODE IS WRONG DO NOT COPY */
```

will *not* catch the `std::runtime_error*` you threw. It'll probably die with a call to `std::terminate` for the uncaught exception.

Don't allocate the exception with `new`, just throw the constructor by-value, e.g.

```
try {
    /* note: no 'new' here */
    throw std::runtime_error("catch me");
} catch (std::runtime_error &err) {
    std::cerr << "exception caught and ignored: " << err.what() << std::end;
}
```

Comment: Silly me! You saved my day.

Comment: Wow thanks man! this was exactly it, new to cpp from java haha

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm most comfortable with C# and throw new is how you do it in that language.  Spent a massive amount of time putting exception handling everywhere and it still wasn't catching.  This suggestion saved me!

Comment: You have no idea how much time I spent swearing at this problem before I figured it out myself, hence this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a
    catch (...)
block to get it.

Comment: He IS `catch`ing, but catching the wrong exception.

Comment: And the `catch(...)` would catch what he throws. I do not understand the downvote.

Comment: This is like saying, "OK, you are learning the arts of wood carving, have this chainsaw and start your first figurine", it is better to have a solution that would lead them to learn the right way for correcting the problem.

Comment: It would be wonderful if we all wrote everything right the first time.  In a case like this, I like to establish something starts working, and refine it from there.

Answer (score 2):

This also may happen when you throw an exception of a an inherted type but the inhertence is private

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not a *MCVE* (what is `Core`?), I can't address explicitly the problem, but you are surely missing to

```
#include <exception>
```

Actually, GCC compiles even without the inclusion, but exception won't be caught and you will end up with

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::exception'
>
> what():  std::exception
>
> ./{program}:  {PID} Aborted                 (core dumped)

Comment: and why this is happning